# How to display just the time instead of day,month,time and GMT in kotlin/android..?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have written the code which shows day,date,time and GMT.I want to just display time for today and time changes to date as the day passed.I am creating offline app. [image: **Screenshot of the app running on mobile**]

I have searched a lot but found nothing.

**InboxActivity File**

```
private fun refreshSmsInbox() {
            val smsList = ArrayList<SmsData>()
            val cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null,null,null,null)
            cursor?.let{
                if(it!!.moveToFirst()){


                    val dateID = it.getColumnIndex("date")
                    do{
                        val dateString = it.getString(dateID)
                        val sms = SmsData(getContactName(this,it.getString(nameID!!.toInt()).toString()),it.getString(messageID),Date(dateString.toLong()).toString())
                        smsList.add(sms)
                    }while (it.moveToNext())
                }
                it.close()
            }
```

**ListAdapter File**

```
class ListAdapter (val context: Context, val list : ArrayList<SmsData>): BaseAdapter(){
    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout,parent,false)


        view.sms_date.text = list[position].date

        return  view
    }
```

**row_layout XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:padding="10dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/sender"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/sms_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Expected**

```
12:33 am/pm
```

next day changes to date. `30 jul 2019`

**Actual**

```
Mon Jul 29 11:44:01 GMT + 05:00 2019
```

Comment: You should change date format nothing else

Comment: How to change this..?

Comment: and in which file..?As I have posted three files..

Comment: Dig a google with _Convert one date format to another dateformat_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To format our date to different formats we can use SimpleDateFormat method and supply to it our custom format using format method:

```
val parser =  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") //Input date formate
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a") //Output date formate
val formattedDate = formatter.format(parser.parse("2018-12-14T09:55:00"))
```

Comment: where I have to place this in the inbox or in the listadapter

Comment: refreshSmsInbox()

Comment: My logcat is not stopping that is why I have applied try catch method I got the Toast message "Bad class : class.java.lang.String "

Comment: Show me your logcat

Comment: My logcat is not stopping thats why I cannot copy paste it or take its screenshot

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you need to show: `12:33 am/pm`

I think something like that should help you:

```
class ListAdapter(val context: Context, val list: ArrayList<SmsData>) : BaseAdapter() {
    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false)


        val date: Date = list[position].date
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a")
        view.sms_date.text = dateFormat.format(date)

        return view
    }
```

Comment: `dateFormat.format(date)` the date is showing unresolved reference.

Comment: Would you replace Date(dateString.toLong()).toString() with Date(dateString.toLong())?
In that case, you will have a plain Date object inside of SmsData class.

Comment: Otherwise, you can format your Date in your InboxActivity class:
replace: val sms = SmsData(getContactName(this,it.getString(nameID!!.toInt()).toString()),it.getString(messageID),SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(Date(dateString.toLong()).toString()))
And leave ListAdapter as it was.

Comment: Ok I will try this now

Comment: I have tried second method but my app is still cashing

Comment: My logcat is not stopping that is why I have applied try catch method I got the Toast message "Bad class : class.java.lang.String "

Comment: I have applied your first method too.It return invalid long : "09:55 am "